# How can I display and use the android default search field within my android app?

Tags: android

I have an android app which needs a search feature. So I was thinking instead of creating a new layout with an editext, a button, and a listview, why not use the android default search field for searching within my app. I've seen it being implemented in other android apps.

For example, let's say I've my android app running on my phone and when I press the search button on my phone, I want my app to open the android built-in search field from the top. And when I enter a search string It would search through some string-arrays and list them using a listview. My first challenge is to have the built-in search field slide open from the top just like any menu slide open from the bottom.

THanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try employing a SearchManager. Android Developers does a very good job detailing how to do this [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introducing-quick-search-box-for.html). They even give you links to other library docs necessary to implement this feature.

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html) could also be of great use.

Comment: I've tried the code, but my app is not showing in the searchable items. And forget about displaying the QSB.

Comment: Perhaps you could offer some relevant code? What errors/exceptions are being thrown? Perhaps the relevant code and a full stack trace will be most beneficial. I will try to help you from there. Also, why are you opposed to the QSB? I thought you wanted the default Android search field. Also, sorry for the late reply. I've been really busy with personal issues, so I haven't been doing much on StackOverflow for a few days now.